# Difference between a constructor with no arguments with a constructor with default arguments

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What is the difference between these two fractions in *C# 5.0* (both to the programmer and to the compiler and *CLR*):

```
public MyClass()
{
    ;   // empty
}

public MyClass(int number = 1, string text = "hello")
{
    ;   // empty
}
```

Comment: Compile it and compare?

Comment: @zerkms I looked up over the CIL. By ignoring the IL's declaration for the two optional parameters in the second ctor, they have absolutely no difference by implementation manner.

Comment: "they have absolutely no difference by implementation manner" --- so you have answered your question?

Comment: Not like that. What wondering me is that why then there's such a duplicate thing in C#.

Comment: "there's such a duplicate thing in C#" --- what thing? You declared a function, compiler compiled it.

Comment: It look likes there is two variables in math like A and B, with values 3 and 5 respectively. I want the result of the subtraction of B from A. Normally, I would do this A - B = -2. But what's happening in C# is there is another method that do this: (A + 10) - B * 2 - 15 = -2. Somewhat like a duplication I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the second ctor, then the generated MSIL contains the default parameters, like you had directly called the ctor with two parameters.

Default parameter values are only syntactical sugar of C#... and should not be used. Use overloaded methods/ctors instead.

Have a look at http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/18/caveats-of-c-4-0-optional-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

It is just like any function, the constructor with parameters will need them. The compiler will automatically add a default constructor if none is provided, but only if  no other constructor definition is supplied. If you include a constructor with parameters, you can no longer use the default constructor and must explicitly define it.

Comment: You answered some other question.

Comment: I think this is wrong: There will not be a default ctor but the existing ctor is called with the default values (in MSIL).